# SSRS rotate textbox?

Tags: reporting-services, textbox

how can I do this?
[image]

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2007/06/01/Reporting-Services---How-to-rotate-text-on-a-report.aspx

> To get text rotated in reporting services all you have to do is set
>   the WritingMode to "tb-rl". You may also want to set the TextAlign and
>   VerticalAlign to position the text correctly. Remember though the text
>   is rotated so to get the text appearing on the left you have to set
>   the VerticalAlign to Bottom. To get the text to align with the bottom
>   of the text box you have to set the TextAlign to Right

http://road-blogs.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/rotate-text-in-ssrs.html

Answer (score 0):

This link shows how you can add custom code to your RDL and it will rotate text 270 degrees so the text starts at the bottom and ends at the top. It keeps coming out fuzzy for me though, I will let you know if I can find a fix to that issue.

http://www.sqljason.com/2011/01/rotate-text-in-ssrs.html